# Kotlin "takeIf" statement equivalent in swift?

Tags: swift

I have this code very simple in kotlin which returns a value if a certain condition is satisfied, or null

```
val speed = location.speed.takeIf { it>=0 }
```

I'm trying to do the same in swift, but the only way I found is this:

```
let speed:Double?
if (location.speed>=0){
    speed = location.speed
}else{
    speed = nil
}
```

Is there any way more elegant?

Comment: You can always use a ternary operator, `let speed = location.speed > 0 ? location.speed : nil`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't something like that in Swift, so we need to find a way to write a `takeIf` function ourselves.

In Kotlin, [`takeIf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) is available on *everything*, as an extension function on all `T`:

```
inline fun <T> T.takeIf(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T?
```

In Swift, you can't write an extension on `Any`, so we can only make a global function:

```
func take<T>(_ value: T, if predicate: (T) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> T? {
    try predicate(value) ? value : nil
}

// example usage:
let x = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
let y = take(x, if: { $0 > 5 })
```

If you are creative enough to think of an operator, you can turn this into an infix operator, similar to how the Kotlin `takeIf` is in between the receiver and the predicate.

```
// I am not creative enough...
infix operator ???

func ???<T>(value: T, predicate: (T) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> T? {
    try predicate(value) ? value : nil
}

let a = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
let b = x ??? { $0 > 5 }
```

Comment: Nice! Good job with this generic solution and the operator!

Answer (score 1):

It's not built into the language, but you can add it.

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Transform `.some` into `.none`, if a condition fails.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - isSome: The condition that will result in `nil`, when evaluated to `false`.
  func filter(_ isSome: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self {
    try flatMap { try isSome($0) ? $0 : nil }
  }
}
```

```swift
let speed = location.speed.filter { $0 >= 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try

`let speed: Double? = location.speed >= 0 ? location.speed : nil`

Swift still supports `? :` if checks, like Java, which are not supported by Kotlin, unless you write an `if () else` .

P.S.: Are you sure you want to return an optional and not 0 if the speed is 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this as a protocol with a default implementation. Then just conform any type to this protocol.

```
protocol Takable {
    func takeIf(_ condition: (Self) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self?
}

extension Takable {
    func takeIf(_ condition: (Self) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self? {
        try condition(self) ? self : nil
    }
}

// Example:
struct Test: Takable {
    let val: Int
}

let t = Test(val: 1)

let a = t.takeIf { $0.val == 1 } // not nil
let b = t.takeIf { $0.val == 2 } // nil
```

Answer (score -5):

You can make extension for Double, like this:

```
extension Double {
    func takeIf() -> Double? {
        if self >= 0 {
            return self
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```